# ubuntu usb UEFI stuck to purple screen

Tags: usb, uefi

it's been 3 days that i'm trying to boot a live from USB but ubuntu get suck everytime with the purple screen, i downloaded 2 versions of ubuntu, tried several programs to transfer the ISO to USB and disabled fast and secure boot but I still have this problem.
My computer is an Asus P553M with windows 10 
Thanks

Comment: Is yours a Bay Trail?  Issues with Bay Trail freeze need boot parameter: intel_idle.max_cstate=1 or patches, see comments
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051
Many Intel Bay Trail Devices Have Been Borked On Linux For The Past Year - Mar 2016
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-Linux-Bay-Trail-Fail

Comment: do i have to put that parameter pressing "e"  before start the live ?

Comment: If UEFI, you have to add to grub menu both installer boot and first boot after install with e for edit. Then update grub to include all the time. If BIOS you add to purple screen f6. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI BIOS: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Comment: still nothing, i tried to put that command on the grub terminal but nothing

Comment: You add it to linux line in place of quiet splash. Is that what you did? Then it may need different or additional parameters.